# Java - One ActionListener for multiple JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm writing a little Java Application. I have multiple JButtons. The code for each button is exactly the same, thus I want only one ActionListener. But in that ActionListener I need to call "setText()" for the corresponding button, which was clicked. Is that possible? How would I achieve this?

I tried the following:

```
private void btnClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  (JButton)evt.setText("Hello");
}
```

But that doesn't work - it says "Cannot find symbol".

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(JButton)evt.setText("Hello");
```

The `ActionEvent` class doesn't have a getText() method.

You need to invoke the `getSource()` method to access the button, then you can invoke the getText() method of the button.

I always like to do it the long way so I don't make mistakes:

```
JButton button = (JButton)evt.getSource();
button.setText( "Hello" );
```

but the short way would be:

```
((JButton)evt.getSource()).setText("Hello");
```